# Как сказать IntelliJ IDEA, что это Maven проект и это его pom.xml?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Idea не понимает, что это за файл `pom.xml` и не подкачивает зависимости. Можно ли как-то явно указать это ?

Comment: Ознакомьтесь со [статьей](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/importing-project-from-maven-model.html) ,пожалуйста. там описано как добавить проект как мавеновский

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file -> other settings ->
```

далее выйдет диалоговое окно, в котором вы сможете настроить все необходимые плагины для работы.
Скорее всего, именно отсутствие галочки нужного плагина не дает разобрать идее мавен.
Еще надо настрить его чтобы идея знала где находится ваш установленный мавен:

```
file -> settings -> maven
```

Там вы должны будете настроить где лежит установленный maven.

﻿﻿﻿﻿[image: введите сюда описание изображения]